# Show calendars that are shared with my Google account in third-party calendars (iCal, Fantastical)

Tags: google-calendar, google-account, sharing

My work uses Exchange, so I use Fantastical on mobile and Apple Calendar/iCal on my Mac to display both my work calendar (in Exchange) and my personal Google Calendar.

I have two calendars in my Google Calendar that were shared with my Google Calendar account by their owner (both are also Google Calendar). I also have a variety of subscribed public calendars. For some reason, when I add a Google account both to iCal and Fantastical, I see my subscribed public calendars but not the private calendars.

I also went to see if I could manually add the .ical, but I don't see a link for the .ical in the Google Calendar web interface.

I suppose I could ask the calendar owner to share their Google Calendar with my work account, but it seems like there should be another way? Given that it's been shared with my Google Calendar account and that I have logged into Google Calendar.

Comment: This question needs more focus. P.S. You might see subscribed caledars because they are public but not the private because apps likd Fantastical and Apple Calendar do not pass authorization credentials. You might create special urls to allow these apps to download private calendars. The Google Calendar Help has information about this. If you still need help, make your question more focused, search this site and the respective documentation for end-users thoroughly, share what you have tried, what you found and why it didn't meet your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify which "subscribed calendars" like this you wish to appear through the Google Calendar API (and thus appear *in* apps like Fantastical) by visiting Google Calendar's "syncselect" page. This is mentioned specifically in Fantastical's Settings pane:

[image]

As mentioned there, you can visit:

> **https://www.google.com/calendar/syncselect**

... and any shared calendars you select at the bottom of that page, will then show up as calendars you can show/hide inside Fantastical itself. (This may take a second to synchronize; consider rebooting Fantastical.)